# npm start error after moving contents of React app to another folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I wrapped the contents of my React app in a 'frontend' folder when I started developing a backend. Now the app won't start. Should I deinstall and reinstall node?
Here is my debug log.

[image]

Comment: Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` , after that run `npm install` again

Comment: Thanks! Got it back already